# How to find out which page is sending the $_POST form data?

Tags: php, jquery

I have to write a quiz application in which I have different pages which send the selected answers to a 'results.php' which then queries the database to the related table to compare the answers with the 'answerkey' table.

I want to selectively query different tables from a database depending on which page the post data came from.

Say if the data came from 'functions.php', i would query the 'functions' table.

How can this be implemented?

Comment: Try this code if you want to take the file name like you mentioned `echo basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], ".php");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to selectively query different tables from a database depending on...

Simply include a hidden field in the form which contains whatever flag you would use to determine this condition.  Something as simple as:

```
<input type="hidden" name="sourcePage" value="Functions" />
```

Then in the server-side code you could retrieve that value:

```
$_POST['sourcePage']
```

Basically, the information being sent to the server is already in a form, so when you want to include more information just include it in that form.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily by adding a second form input field which is hidden from the user.

For example:

```
<input type="hidden" name="the_page_requester" value="name_of_page" />
```

And in your php code you can do the following:

```
$pageRequester = $_POST['the_page_requester']
```

Answer (score 0):

The global variable `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` should contain the URL from which the request was submitted

Comment: Do not use $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] as it is highly unreliable and can cause issues down the road

Comment: I checked the documentation. The solution provided by  David fulfils my needs.

Comment: 'HTTP_REFERER'
    The address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a feature. **In short, it cannot really be trusted**. 

see http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Answer (score -1):

I think this solution is better:

```
$table = pathinfo($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])['filename'];
```

now you can use `$table` to Assemble your sql.

Comment: This would return the path of the *currently executing* script, not the previous page.